# How to create a zip file containing a custom Python module for AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Let's say I have the following folder structure on my local setup:

```
wallpaper-generator
|
+-- WallpaperGenerator.py
|
+-- assets
|   |
|   +-- Roboto-Bold.ttf
|
+-- venv
    |
    +-- lib
        |
        +-- python3.7
            |
            +-- site-packages
                |
                +-- qrcode
                |
                +-- PIL
```

Essentially, the module is called `WallpaperGenerator.py`, and it imports an asset (font) using the following file path: `assets/Roboto-Bold.ttf`. Moreover, the only 3rd party libraries being used are `PIL` and `qrcode`, and both of these are used in `WallpaperGenerator.py` like so:

```
import qrcode
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

...
```

The `WallpaperGenerator.py` has a function called `generate_wallpaper()`. What I actually want to do is import this function into my Lambda event handler and just call it to produce the result and return the response, so something like this:

```
from WallpaperGenerator import generate_wallpaper

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ...
    generate_wallpaper(...)
    ...
    return response
```

How do I create/structure my zip file to upload to Lambda? What should be the filename for this zip file? I'm not even sure if such a module type workflow even possible with Lambda. Can anyone help me get started, or at least point me in the right direction? I find the AWS docs really intimidating. Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's definitely possible to do. You should check the documentation how to package Python code for AWS Lambda. This should include all necessary information you need: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html
To make packaging and deployment easier there also exist tools like AWS SAM: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build.html